# Javascript document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, getelementbyid, var

Im not sure why this is not working, can someone please tell me why?

```
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var myName = document.getElementById('mytext');
letterColors = [ red, orange, green, blue, purple ]
if(10 >  3) {
bubbleShape = "circle";
}

else {
    bubbleShape = "square";
}
drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceBubbles()

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<head>
  Name: <input type="text" name="mytext"><br>
</form>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the variable "myname" to be what the user types into the text box.

Comment: mytext is not an ID its a name property

Comment: The element is not available when you're trying to get it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the reference to the element, but then you need to use the `value` property to the value from the element:

```
var myName = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
```

You need to set the id of the element to access it using the `getElementById` method:

```
<input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext">
```

Also, it's not clear where the Javascript code is executed in the code, but if the code is the entire content of the `alphabet.js`, `bubble.js` or `main.js` file, then you are running the code before the content of the body has been parsed. To run the code after the content is loaded, use the `load` event:

```
window.onload = function(){

  // code that uses the content goes in here

};
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: When I do this there is no submit button, did I do something wrong. How do I add a submit button?    PS, I was not the one who down voted

Comment: @user3579132: You have no submit button in the code, you have to add code for it if you want one, for example: `<input type="submit" value="Send">`. There are some things wrong, actually; you have no `<form>` tag to start the form, and there is a `<head>` and a `</head>` tag in the middle of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

set ID property to your input tag

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="text" name="mytext">
```

To

```
 <input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext">
```

Then use

```
var myName = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
```

Like @Guffaa suggested.

Comment: When I do this there is no submit button, did I do something wrong. How do I add a submit button?